# invalid instruction suffix when assembling x86 assembly with as

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I wrote an assembly program that assemble successfully with `as --32` when I use `pushl` and `popl` in the following code snippet:

```
  PrintHelloWorld:
    movl $10, %ecx
    PrintTenTimes:
      pushl %ecx
      movl $4, %eax
      movl $1, %ebx
      leal HelloWorld, %ecx
      movl $14, %edx
      int $0x80
      popl %ecx
    loop PrintTenTimes
    jmp ExitCall
```

But when I tried to assembly for 64-bit machines, I get the following error:

```
ConditionalBranching.s: Assembler messages:
ConditionalBranching.s:51: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
ConditionalBranching.s:57: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `pop'
```

So I change pushl and popl into pushq and popq, then I get the following error:

```
ConditionalBranching.s: Assembler messages:
ConditionalBranching.s:51: Error: operand type mismatch for `push'
ConditionalBranching.s:57: Error: operand type mismatch for `pop'
```

How to remove this error and assemble successfully for 64-bit?

Comment: You can't push a 32bit quantity at all in 64bit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're most likely still trying to push the 32-bit `eax` rather than having upgraded your instruction correctly to:

```
pushq %rax
```

That's based that on the fact that the error message is now complaining about an *operand type mismatch* rather than the suffix.

As per the Intel documentation, the 32-bit register push instruction is not encodable in 64-bit mode:

[image]